# React input misses keystrokes on mobile browser

Tags: reactjs, input, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete input form that works perfectly when used from a desktop browser. Even if I heavily throttle the CPU using Chrome dev-tools.

The issue comes when using such input from a mobile device. If I type too fast, it'll miss some keystrokes (i.e. if I try to type "React", only "rct" might be captured.

It's worth noting that, even if I use Chrome's device toolbar to emulate the navigation from a mobile device, I'm not able to replicate the bug.

I have tried to gain insights by using React's profiler, but the component in question renders in 10ms on average, and I have run out of ideas. Using React 18's new `useDeferredValue` and `useTransition` hooks didn't help either, and debouncing the input only helps to some extent: If the typing happens to occur exactly after the debounce time finished, the bug will show up.

The component in question looks like this:

```
export const UsersSearchAutocomplete = ({ zIndex, isDesktop }: { zIndex: number; isDesktop: boolean }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [autocompleteState, setAutocompleteState] = useState<AutocompleteState<UserSearchable>>({
    collections: [],
    isOpen: false,
    activeItemId: null,
    completion: null,
    query: '',
    status: 'idle',
    context: {},
  });
  const deferredAutocompleteState = useDeferredValue(autocompleteState);

  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
  const panelRef = useRef(null);

  const onFormKeyUp = useCallback((evt: React.KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (evt.key === 'a' && evt.ctrlKey) {
      evt.stopPropagation();
    }
  }, []);

  const usersSearchIndex = useMemo(() => client.index('users'), [client]);

  const autocomplete = useMemo(
    () =>
      createAutocomplete({
        placeholder: 'search',
        onStateChange: ({ state }) => setAutocompleteState(state),
        getSources: () => [
          {
            sourceId: 'meilisearch_users',
            getItems: ({ query }: GetSourcesParams<UserSearchable>) => {
              if (query.trim()) {
                return usersSearchIndex
                  .search<UserSearchable>(query, { limit: 5 })
                  .then((searchResponse) => searchResponse.hits)
                  .catch((err) => {
                    if (err instanceof Error) {
                      captureException(err);
                    }
                    return [];
                  });
              }

              return [];
            },
            getItemUrl: ({ item: user }) => {
              return profilePage.url(user.profile_address);
            },
          },
        ],
        shouldPanelOpen(params) {
          return Boolean(params.state.query.trim().length);
        },
        navigator: {
          navigate: ({ item: user }) => {
            router
              .push(profilePage.pagePath(user.profile_address), profilePage.url(user.profile_address))
              .catch(captureException);
          },
          navigateNewTab({ itemUrl }) {
            const windowReference = window.open(itemUrl, '_blank', 'ugc nofollow noopener noreferrer');

            if (windowReference) {
              windowReference.focus();
            }
          },
          navigateNewWindow({ itemUrl }) {
            window.open(itemUrl, '_blank', 'ugc nofollow noopener noreferrer');
          },
        },
      }),
    [usersSearchIndex, router, localize]
  );

  const onInputBlur = useCallback(() => {
    setAutocompleteState((curr) => ({ ...curr, isOpen: false }));
  }, []);

  return (
      <form
        onKeyUp={onFormKeyUp}
        {...autocomplete.getFormProps({
          inputElement: inputRef.current,
        })}
      >
        <div>
          <SearchIcon className="searchIcon" />
          <input
            ref={inputRef}
            {...autocomplete.getInputProps({
              inputElement: inputRef.current,
            })}
            // eslint-disable-next-line jsx-a11y/no-autofocus
            autoFocus={!isDesktop}
            onBlur={onInputBlur}
          />
          {deferredAutocompleteState.isOpen && (
              <div ref={panelRef} {...autocomplete.getPanelProps()} zIndex={zIndex}>
                {deferredAutocompleteState.collections.map((collection, i) => {
                  const { items: users, source } = collection;

                  return (
                    <section key={`section-${i}`}>
                      {users.length > 0 && (
                        <li {...autocomplete.getListProps()}>
                          {users.map((userSearchable) => {
                            return (
                              <div key={userSearchable.id}>
                                <li
                                  {...autocomplete.getItemProps({ item: userSearchable, source })}
                                >
                                  <img src={userSearchable.avatar} />
                                  <span>{userSearchable.name}</span>
                                </li>
                              </div>
                            );
                          })}
                        </ul>
                      )}
                    </section>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
          )}
          {deferredAutocompleteState.isOpen &&
            deferredAutocompleteState.status === 'idle' &&
            deferredAutocompleteState.collections.flatMap((collection) => collection.items).length === 0 && (
                <div ref={panelRef} {...autocomplete.getPanelProps()} zIndex={zIndex}>
                  <li>No users found</li>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
      </form>
  );
};
```

Comment: what is the code you're trying to fix?

Comment: @SashaKondrashov, I have added a sans-style code snippet of the component